# Collapsable div, but from a certain point defined in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

E.g. I have a div that contains all the text like:

```
<div class="text-container">
<p>
Though we welcome the idea of a smaller connector, we're miffed that Apple couldn't just adopt the semi-industry standard of Micro-USB. That would make things easier for smartphone users across the globe. Yet, even so, the smaller connector may be a smart move for the future. The 30-pin connector has been around since 2003, long before the iPhone even existed: frankly, it's a dust magnet. A smaller connector helps shave extra space to achieve a smaller phone with perhaps a bigger battery. The new connector cable will mainly be used for syncing and charging by most people who own an Apple TV or Bluetooth/AirPlay accessories.
</p>
</div>
```

And I would like to create something like this:

```
<div class="text-container">
<p>
Though we welcome the idea of a smaller connector...<a href="some-javascript-to-show-more">[show more]</a>
</p>
</div>
```

I guess I should get all the content of the div and then Find the first e.g. 50 character and put there a link and all the other text put in some div which will be hidden, and after the click on the link the other stuff show up.

It should be toggle-like and change the text from [show more] to [show less] if it is expanded and vice versa.

Any advice how to achieve this with plain javascript and jquery itself and without other jQuery plugins?

Comment: you have already answered your question "I guess I should get all the content of the div and then Find the first e.g. 50 character and put there a link and all the other text put in some div which will be hidden, and after the click on the link the other stuff show up."

Comment: yes, but I am not so good in javascript and jquery, that I can solve it myself. I need a little help with a little code how to approach this problem. I am sure that someone else will benefit from this in the future too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution.

It doesn't simply cut the words in the middle but checks endings, punctuation, and long words.

```
$(".text-container p").each(function() {
    var val = $.trim(this.innerHTML),
        parsed = val.split(/\s+/),
        cut = parsed;

    // for each word
    for (var i = 0, k = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
        k += parsed[i].length + 1;

        if (k - 1 > 50) {
            cut = parsed.slice(0, i);
            break;
        }
    }

    // if one long word
    if (cut.length == 0) {
        cut.push(parsed[0].substring(0, 50));
    }

    val = cut.join(" ");

    // if the text is long enough to cut
    if (cut.length != parsed.length) {
        this.innerHTML = val.replace(/[.,;?!]$/, "")
            + "<span>...</span> ";

        $("<span />")
            .css("display", "none")
            .html(parsed.slice(cut.length).join(" ") + " ")
            .appendTo(this);

        $("<a />", {
            href : "#",
            text : "[show more]"
        }).on("click", function(e) {
            var sh = this.innerHTML == "[show more]";
            $(this).prev("span").toggle(sh).prev("span").toggle(!sh);
            this.innerHTML = sh ? "[show less]" : "[show more]";
            e.preventDefault();
        }).appendTo(this);
    } else {
        this.innerHTML = val;
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xRuch/

Comment: @Derfder Glad that it justified the time spent :)

Answer (score 1):

Build a quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/37RqC/1/) for you

jQuery

```
$(function(){
   var $el = $(".text-container").find("p");
   var str = $el.text();
   var str1 = str.substr(0,50), str2=  str.substr(51);
   $el.html(str1+" <span class='showMore'><a href='#'>Show more...</a></span><span class='moreText'>"+str2+"</span><span class='showLess'><a href='#'>Show Less</a></span>");

    $(".showMore").on("click", function(){
        $(this).next(".moreText").show();
        $(this).next(".moreText").next(".showLess").show();
        $(this).hide();
    });

     $(".showLess").on("click", function(){
        $(this).prev(".moreText").hide();
        $(this).prev(".moreText").prev(".showMore").show();
        $(this).hide();
    })

});
```

css

```
.moreText, .showLess { display:none};
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising. I will try it and give you a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

on modern browsers you could use the css property `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8skB/1/

i used css in my example to expand the text, but you could also do it with jquery if you want a `show more` link.

Comment: Thanks that is great, however I cannot rely on modern browsers, because the users are using old browser also. So, javascript is the only solution.

Comment: @Derfder i just checked and seems like browser support isn't all that bad: http://caniuse.com/text-overflow, but maybe i can hack up a javascript solution later when i have some time:)

Comment: -1 where is [show more], [show less]? Plus, I don't want hover I need on click event. Plus, your solution is not working in IE6, IE6 are using still 20% of my webpage visitors. Plus, I was asking for javascript and jquery solution.

Comment: @Derfder Sorry, i didn't realize that your post wasn't a question but a demand for a full solution. I was just offering a possible alternative solution to your problem which, as i stated, could easily be extended with javascript to show a more link.